# how should i put my method(with array) in a switch statement in java?

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

whats the right way to put a method(with array code) in a switch statement?

```
    public static void  prtEmployees(String empNo[], String Name[], int rate[]) {
    System.out.println("Employee No.    Employee Name   Rate/Hour");
    for(int i = 0; i < empNo.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%s: %s", empNo[i], Name[i], rate[i]);
    }

}
private void Action(int choice) {
switch(choice) {
case 1:
    prtEmployees(); // im having an error here
    break;
```

Comment: The method you are calling has tree parameters, however you are supplying none. Is this the error you are having?

Comment: yes, i already tried to put (String empNo[], String Name[], int rate[]) on it but still having an error

Comment: You do not instantiate arrays this way. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java#:~:text=Java%20array%20is%20an%20object,elements%20in%20a%20Java%20array.).

Comment: @Mushroomator if you mean that i still dont have java arrays, like int rate[] = {150,250,250,300,300,450,250,450};.i already have it(in my main) but i just didnt put it here because its kinda long code. or i shouldnt put it in my main?

Comment: You need to pass array instances to your `prtEmployees()` method. So you will need them in your `Action()` method at some point. You either instantiate them there or you pass them as a parameter to `Action()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is not about using a switch, but calling a method with a wrong amount of parameters.
The method **prtEmployees** requires 3 parameters:

1. String array of employee no's
2. String array of employee names
3. Int array of employee rates

The 3 parameters are **always** required to be placed.

Based on your code snippet, I can't see where your input is, where your employee data is coming from. But I created a sample where I call your method in a main class with some dummy data to give an example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] employeeNos = {"1", "2", "3"};
        String[] names = {"Alfred", "James", "Siegfried"};
        int[] rates = {2,3,5};

        Action(1, employeeNos, names, rates);
        Action(2, employeeNos, names, rates);
    }

    public static void  prtEmployees(String[] employeeNumbers, String[] names, int[] rates) {
        System.out.print("Employee No.\tEmployee Name\tRate/Hour\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < employeeNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s.\t%s\t%d\n", employeeNumbers[i], names[i], rates[i]);
        }

    }
    private static void Action(int choice, String[] employeeNos, String[] names, int[] rates) {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                prtEmployees(employeeNos, names, rates);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("No employee print because of choice 1");
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only choice 1 and 2 are allowed");
        }
    }
}
```

This gives as output:

> Employee No.  Employee Name   Rate/Hour
>
> 1. Alfred  2
> 2. James   3
> 3. Siegfried   5
>    Only choice 1 and 2 are allowed

**Explanation**
First I call the action method with choice 1 and some dummy data, which will pass the dummy data to the print method and it will print out the 3 columns of employee data.
Then I call the same method with choice value 2, which prints an additional single line, just to illustrate the functionality of it.
Just for fun I added a default behaviour that other values than 1 and 2 will throw an exception.